# Deriving difference from difference of logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Good afternoon.

I know that $\log{x} - \log{y} = -0.204$.
How do I compute $x - y$?

Thanks a lot for your solutions!

Comment: There are infinitely many pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying that first equation and infinitely many values of $x - y$

Comment: I don't know but that implies : $\frac{x}{y}=10^{-0.204}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The given difference of logs determines $x/y$, but it does not determine $x-y$.

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible. Try $y = 1$ and solve for $x$. Then try $y = 2$.